# How can I add orthogonality regularization in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I would like to regularize the layers of a CNN with

```
|(W^T * W - I)|
```

How can I do that in Keras?

Comment: What norm do you want to use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Good question. Intuitively, I would have taken the [2-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#.22Entrywise.22_norms) (Frobeniusnorm). However, this choice is rather arbitrary. I'm not sure how it influences the training.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> Any function that takes in a weight matrix and returns a loss
>   contribution tensor can be used as a regularizer

Here is the example implemented:

```
from keras import backend as K

def l1_reg(weight_matrix):
    return 0.01 * K.sum(K.abs(weight_matrix))

model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,
                kernel_regularizer=l1_reg)
```

the loss in your post would be:

```
from keras import backend as K
def fro_norm(w):
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(K.abs(w))))

def cust_reg(w):
    m = K.dot(K.transpose(w), w) - np.eye(w.shape)
    return fro_norm(m)
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

X = np.random.randn(100, 100)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 1))

model = Sequential()

# apply regularization here. applies regularization to the 
# output (activation) of the layer
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(100,), 
                activity_regularizer=fro_norm))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=32)
```

**Below wouldn't work as hinted by @Marcin's comment  LA.norm wouldn't work since the regularizer must return a Tensor `LA.norm()` doesn't.**

```
def orth_norm(w)
    m = K.dot(k.transpose(w), w) - np.eye(w.shape)
    return LA.norm(m, 'fro')

from keras import backend as K

import numpy as np

def orth_norm(w)
    m = K.dot(k.transpose(w), w) - np.eye(w.shape)
    return LA.norm(m, 'fro')
```

[Keras regularizers](https://keras.io/regularizers)

[Frobenias norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)

Comment: Is this actually working? Norm doesn't seem to be a `keras.backend` function?

Comment: thanks, you're right. I can't seem to find a norm function in the backend, hints?

Comment: You've implemented the Frobenious norm, but the `cust_reg` seems not to work: https://pastebin.com/CgX5rdvE with https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/f29b640caa237e413e05c98d8c334ddd

Comment: I think it should be `m = K.dot(K.transpose(w), w) - K.eye(w[1].shape[0])`. May I replace it?

Answer (score 2):

I think for convolutional layers you could use below code, it is not efficient at all, but I think it works:

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
def orthogonality_regularization(weight_matrix):
    identity = K.eye(int(weight_matrix.shape[-1]))
    orthogonality_reg_mat = []
    for i in range(weight_matrix.shape[-1]):
        for j in range(weight_matrix.shape[-1]):
            orthogonality_reg_mat.extend([K.sum(tf.multiply(K.flatten(weight_matrix[:,:,:,i]), K.flatten(weight_matrix[:,:,:,j]))) - identity[i, j]])

    orthogonality_reg = tf.linalg.norm(tf.convert_to_tensor(orthogonality_reg_mat))


    return orthogonality_reg
```

Comment: Does anybody how should it be implemented more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (new in [`tensorflow 2.9.0`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.9.0#:%7E:text=Added%20tf.keras.regularizers.OrthogonalRegularizer%2C%20a%20new%20regularizer%20that%20encourages%20orthogonality%20between%20the%20rows%20(or%20columns)%20or%20a%20weight%20matrix.)) keras offers a regularization operator for Orthogonal regularization:
[OrthogonalRegularizer](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/#:%7E:text=%5Bsource%5D-,OrthogonalRegularizer,-class). It allows to impose orthogonality between columns and rows, not sure which is your specific case.

So, you can call it just like:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

reg = tf.keras.regularizers.OrthogonalRegularizer(factor=0.01, mode="rows")

# now you can use reg in your layer(s)
```